# Dynamic like scrolling speed

Tags: macos

I've noticed on my mac, in a few programs (Safari/Preview) when I'm looking through a PDF that the scrolling speed sometimes changes.

I'm not sure what it is exactly. At first I thought It was how fast I scroll.

Sometimes it seems like its scrolling further while the page is already moving due to momentum.

I'm not sure what causes the fast scrolling is there anyone who knows what I'm talking about and knows how to control the scrolling speed (im not talking about the settings)

What exactly triggers the speed difference

Comment: Are you talking about momentum scrolling? On multi-touch input devices you can flick with two fingers to scroll a view from anywhere to a few lines to few pages in one direction. Tapping stops the scrolling.

Comment: Yes, on very large documents 60 pages+. If you scroll with two fingers and it scrolls due to momentum, and if you scroll again while on the momentum the speed of scroll increases. I think its this but im not sure how to control it, it goes so fast sometimes tapping is too late, If I knew how to control it I wouldnt let it go so fast